# Insert data through SPARQL over HTTP POST request from node js

Tags: node.js, sparql, ontology, fuseki, http-method

I am using 'request' module in my node app to POST data in ontology model which resides in a fuseki server. I am using the following code:

```js
var request = require('request');
var querystring = require('querystring');

var myquery = querystring.stringify({update: "PREFIX test:<http://www.semanticweb.org/muhammad/ontologies/2017/2/untitled-ontology-14#> INSERT { ?KPIs test:hasValue 2009} WHERE { ?KPIs test:hasValue ?Newvalue}"});


request.post('http://localhost:3030/DS-1/sparql?'+myquery, function (error, response, body) {
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
   // Show the HTML for the Google homepage.
console.log('successful update');
console.log(body);

  } else {
   console.log(response.statusCode);
   console.warn(error);
  }
});
```

PS: When I use POSTMAN to send the Post request to insert data it works fine but from my node app, it doesn't. it shows error 'bad request 400'.
P.S: GET methods work fine from both POSTMAN and node app.

Comment: My guess is the server is looking for form data rather than query parameters, in Postman how are you sending the POST request when it works? Also might be worth doing a `console.log` on `myquery` to see whether that is formed correctly.

Comment: In Postman the query looks like this with the POST method :: http://localhost:3030/DS-1/?update=PREFIX+test%3A%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.semanticweb.org%2Fmuhammad%2Fontologies%2F2017%2F2%2Funtitled-ontology-14%23%3E%0D%0AINSERT+%7B+%3FKPIs+test%3AhasValue+11%7D%0D%0AWHERE%0D%0A++%7B+%3FKPIs+test%3AhasValue+%3FNewvalue%7D.                                                                                                  P.s: I have tried this format in node app but it didn't work, and yes 'myquery' is correctly formed i have checked it and i have also tried directly putting the url like the above one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem Solved:
I was making mistake in the format of post request. The corrected format is given below.

```js
var request = require('request');
var querystring = require('querystring');

var myquery2 = querystring.stringify({update: "PREFIX test:<http://www.semanticweb.org/muhammad/ontologies/2017/2/untitled-ontology-14#> INSERT { ?KPI_Variables test:hasValue_ROB1 2000} WHERE { ?KPI_Variables test:hasValue_ROB1 ?Newvalue FILTER(?KPI_Variables= test:Actual_Production_Time)}"});

request.post({headers: {'content-type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},url:'http://localhost:3030/DS-1/?'+myquery2 }, function (error, response, body) {
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
   // Show the HTML for the Google homepage.
console.log('successful update');
console.log(body);
  } 
  else
  {
   console.log(response.statusCode)
   console.warn(error);
  }
});
```

I was missing the 'headers' and 'url' elements in my request.post.

Answer (score 0):

`/DS-1/sparql` is the query service.

`INSERT` is an update operation.

Try `/DS-1/update`

It is better to POST the update in the body of the request with a Content-type. `?update=` may not work.

Comment: I have tried even that but that also gives the following error: [2017-04-04 11:59:50] Fuseki     INFO  [48] 404 Not found: dataset='DS-1' service='update=PREFIX%20test%3A%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.semanticweb.org%2Fmuhammad%2Fontol
ogies%2F2017%2F2%2Funtitled-ontology-14%23%3E%20INSERT%20%7B%20%3FKPIs%20test%3A
hasValue%202009%7D%20WHERE%20%7B%20%3FKPIs%20test%3AhasValue%20%3FNewvalue%7D'

Comment: Note it is now "404 Not found". Check the configuration of the server to see if update is enabled. (--update, or update if using a config file).